# How do I write and run an upgrade script for .sdf databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, upgrade, sqlcmd

How do I write and run an upgrade script for .sdf databases?  Would sqlcmd be able to do that?  I am not trying to upgrade the version of the database file.  I am trying to upgrade the schema and data inside of it.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same.  I tried using:

sqlcmd -E -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -d master -Q "EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname=N'ExDB', @filename1 = N'%dbdir%\TestDB.sdf'" 

but I get an error telling me that it's not a valid database file header.  I'll post here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

***Rewritten***

You can use [SQL Compact's TSQL commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173372(v=SQL.100).aspx), such as [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123(v=SQL.100).aspx) and [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174122(v=SQL.100).aspx).

This can be done with your choice of client, whether inside an application using the [SqlServerCe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.aspx) namespace methods (you'll need to reference the SQL Compact library) or with a client like SQL Server Management Studio.

Just remember that SQL Compact only allows one process to be connected to the database at a time.

Comment: I'm really looking for a scriptable command line utility that I can use as part of my checkout process...

Comment: Josh, did you ever find an answer for this? I would like to generate my SDF file from a SQL script as part of my build process also.

Comment: For a scriptable command-line utility you could consider using PowerShell and the `SqlServerCe` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script against a SQL CE database manually as follows:

- Open **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
- Click **New Query** on the toolbar. A dialog headed "Connect to server" comes up
- Set **Server Type** to "SQL Server Compact Edition"
- For the **Database file** field enter the full path to the `.sdf` file
- click **Connect**

You should get a query window which you can use to execute scripts in the usual way. And see the database in the Object explorer.